# Setting up multiple domain tracking on GA

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, tracking

I have a website structure of www.website.com, www.website.at, m.website.com, m.website.at and I am trying to set up a GA property which will track all of them using cross-domain tracking. How do I set this up if I can only use one URL per property on GA?

I have read the Google documentation but I still cannot seem to understand how to set this up.

Comment: The domain setting in properties and views is used as base url for in-page analysis and page preview (i.e. reporting only), it does not affect tracking in any way. If you keep that in mind the documentation possibly makes more sense.

Comment: Ok so in this case if I set one property in GA and then use the same property code in each website, how do I filter the data in GA? Can I use segments or something of the sort?

Comment: You use either segments, or you can filter domains into separate views (altough this negates the advantages of cross-domain tracking). You also might want to add domain names to the reported page paths (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012243?hl=en) else similar paths from different domains will be lumped together in the reports.

Comment: Thanks so much! This seems to be working so far :)

Comment: Ok so I have managed to see how I can track multiple domains in one property. My problem now is that I am not managing to do cross-domain tracking. I followed the tutorial here http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/06/16/cross-domain-tracking-with-google-tag-manager/ but I cannot see the Linker loader parameter in the URL. Any ideas why? Could it be because the redirection happens after login?